# For TCP ports on hostname "localhost": $ serve -l 5002 command -l not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache2, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up a new service and enable a site on my Digital Ocean Droplet using apache2.  I am using npm serve and have the command `-l` in a path however, when I run the command, I'm getting the error that `-l: command not found`

I see in `serve --help` that `-l` will over write the default `--listen` argument.  I need to do this because I already have a service running on `0.0.0.0:5000`

this is the full command I'm attempting `ExecStart=/home/danhemerlein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/serve -l 5002 -s /home/danhemerlein/test`

Thanks!!

Comment: Remove the `ExecStart=` from the command, because like this the command you are actualy executing is `-l 5002 -s /home/danhemerlein/test`. What do you think the `ExecStart=` does in this case?

Comment: Ok, that did help with running the command.  I guess my confusion is because I'm getting a 127 status when trying to run this as a systemd service.  127 meaning the command is not found.  So I was trying to run the command on its own to further diagnose the problem.  Here's the other error I'm getting if you might be able to help: `Process: 8217 ExecStart=/home/danhemerlein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/serve -l 5002 -s 
 Main PID: 8217 (code=exited, status=127)`

Comment: full error: `Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2019-07-09 12:41:32 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 8323 ExecStart=/home/danhemerlein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/serve -l 5002 -s 
 Main PID: 8323 (code=exited, status=127)
`